# Div Slide bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am searching for the function i don't know the name.
please have a look on image you will understand what i am looking for.
any help will be appreciated.  [image: i have to use this function in wordpress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [jQuery accordion](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&cp=9&gs_id=y&xhr=t&q=jquery+accordion&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=jquery+ac&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=91d39effc89b4eaa&biw=1280&bih=833). There are plenty of plugins out there, one of which should suit your needs. Even if there isn't writing your own is pretty easy.